# Not able to get the PostGIS Layer Viewer running in pgAdmin or command line

Tags: qgis, python, postgis, pgadmin-3, postgis-layer-viewer

I've installed PostGIS Layer Viewer as a plugin for pgAdmin. I've downloaded postgis_viewer.py from the official repository on [GitHub](https://github.com/gacarrillor/postgis-layer-viewer)! and followed the install instructions described on [Web site](http://geotux.tuxfamily.org/index.php/en/geo-blogs/item/293-consola-sql-para-plugin-pgadmin-postgis-viewer/)!. I've also checked the installation prerequisites and made sure that all ini-files are set accordance with my own directories layout. After running the plugin in pgAdmin the application stalls. And by stalling I mean that no layer becomes visible.

[image: dosbox] [image: pluginwindow]

The pgAdmin version I am using is version 1.20.0 on Windows7 64bit OS. The QGIS version I am using is 2.8.1.

The question I have is how to get the plugin running?

NB! I also tried running the application from the command line but the results were the same.

Comment: I think you need to provide us with more details. For example: What type of layer you want to visualize? Do you get any error message when you run the script from the command line? Does the user/password you're using have permission to access that layer? What exactly is the command you're running?